# .htaccess rewrite won't work correctly on prod server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I've created this .htaccess in the root of my site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*admin/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*api/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*css/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*images/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*js/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*libs/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.+.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?game=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1/ [R,L]
```

The weird thing is, on my personal server it all works fine, but on my prod server hosted by name.com, accessing the /admin/ path boots me back to the/ of the site. Any ideas?

UPDATE: The .htaccess from the admin/ folder:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Somename"
AuthUserFile /home/username/.htpasswd
```

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess in `/admin/` folder as well?

Comment: Yes, though it only contains password stuff

Comment: Ok but in that case above root .htaccess is being ignored for `/admin/`

Comment: Then why does it work on my test server?

Comment: Well I don't have access to your test server so cant say.

Comment: Well just within this reasoning then, if the root .htaccess is being ignored, shouldn't it just let me access the folder then? Why would that bump me back to the root folder?

Comment: That could be due to rules in /admin/ or else some code.

Comment: As I said, there aren't any rules in /admin/. I posted the contents of the .htaccess file in the question. Where else should I look for conflicting rules?